# how to control dynamic rows coming from a form in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have a form which sends over dynamic number of rows and columns. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/) on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuW6/) of how the form looks like.

I have columns of Red, Yellow, and Green and there could be dynamic number of rows associated with these colors shades. Each row has a text box and check boxes.

How can I keep account for what got selected by the user in my controller `save()` action?

For example for the following screenshot from the form

[image]

I get the following response back to my controller:

```
[red:on, green:[on, on], shade:[light, dark, , ], action:save]
```

**Question**

Now the problem is that even though I have all the shades the user entered I don't have a way to connect back which rows had the checkboxes checked for different color columns.

I'm interested in knowing how to do this in Grails/Rails or other frameworks as well.

Comment: Probably you didn't set "id" on checkboxes. ID should be generated with line number for such problem. For example row:1:red, row:1:green, etc. But if I had to implement this, I would use JSON to send the data.

Comment: I agree with @droggo I would use JSON too. If you contruct your JSON object with the Shades params like {light:[{red:on], {yellow:off},{green:on}], dark:[{red:on], {yellow:off},{green:on}] ...

Comment: do you mean you would use JSON to submit the form and send the data back to the controller?

Comment: No. I would construct JSON object using javascript. and execute standard JSON POST request to other controller method. for example using jquery: $.ajax({type:'POST', contentType:'application/json', data:JSON, url:'/AppName/controller/action'})

Answer (score 0):

So you have to increment your names:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="red.1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="red.2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="red.3" />
```

Then you can loop over them like so:

```
params.list("red").each {
}
```